# images aren't displayed after uploading it to the host

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a landing page and when I'm testing it locally on my computer it does display 3 certain images. When I upload it to the host it doesn't?

I've re-uploaded the images but still no result. I've used both Chrome and Safari.

It shows the 3 questions marks instead of the images.
They are in the same folder as the `index.html` file and I'm using this path:

`<img src="img1.png" id="picture1" class="img-responsive" />`

Comment: Can you check the paths to make sure you are looking in the right place? Are you uploading to a 'Nix server? Because then you will need to make sure your links to the images are correct and case-sensitive. Can you see the error logs for the server?

Comment: Are you using absolute file paths?

Comment: Probably path issue. You need to help us help you - show us the HTML for the <img> tags, and tell us what folder your HTML file and images are in.

Comment: <img src="img1.png" id="picture1" class="img-responsive" />

Comment: and they are in the same folder as the index.html folder

Comment: @user2758874 Your images may not have permission to be visible. Try setting the permission of all images to 755.

Comment: not sure what you mean I'm using basic hosting and never had this issue. And like I mentioned above the logo which is also a png and in the same folder is being displayed.

Comment: @user2758874 how are you uploading your files to the server? In Filezilla, right click on the file in the server, select File Attributes, and change the Numerical Value to 755.

Comment: I've changed the value to 755 still a no show. So strange

Comment: are you absolutely sure your filename is right? It's not `img1.PNG` instead of `.png`?

Comment: yeah I'm sure like I said it works fine locally. But as soon as I upload it it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry my mistake :(. For some reason locally it accepts .png but when I change it to PNG it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably since you were developing on your local machine the image location is different than the image location on your host server. For example on your local machine you would use `<img src="desktop/file/image_folder/pic.jpg">` but on your hosting server there isn't a desktop, so most probably you need to double check the image source. Please edit your post with the code for your image source.

Comment: they are in the same folder as the index.html file and I'm using this path:

Comment: <img src="img1.png" id="picture1" class="img-responsive" />

Comment: @user2758874 The image code that you posted that you provided is it in `index.html`, and from what I understand is that both the `index.html` and the image are in the same folder?

Comment: the strange thing is that the logo (which is also a image) and is also in the same folder is being displayed.

Comment: Could you add the whole code of your `index.html` in your post? Use the `edit` button under your main post please.

Comment: I tried but for some reason stack overflow keep rejecting me to post to code even when I use the {}.

Comment: @user2758874 I would suggest going on pastebin and pasting your code there and sharing the link here for me to have a look at it.